# Dataset - Where can I find a dataset about different car instances about their original prices/retail value?

Tags: database, statistics

I am looking for statistical analysis a data set, which contains car instances with its' respective information like brand, model, year when produced, and maybe some other key values as well (but that's just the bonus), AND car price when it was brand new - out of the factory.

**Some extra background**

I have a data set with about 120,000 used cars and I would like to do some statistical analysis, how the value has been decreased over the time etc.

I have found some webpages, which contain the value, which I am looking for, but in those cases it seems that I would have to do some webpage crawling to get my values out of there in the automatic manner. Also that would be against the terms of the page - stealing the data from them, stealing is bad.

I have worked out of some Stackoverflow topics, but those links on those topics don't contain any information about the price when the car models were new.

Good datasets or APIs, without the price when new:

- http://www3.epa.gov/otaq/tcldata.htm
- http://developer.edmunds.com/api-documentation/overview/index.html
- http://www.carqueryapi.com/

Comment: good question; keep me posted

Comment: did you have any luck on this?

Comment: What where the webpages where you could get the price of a car when it was new?

Comment: @subharb I used https://www.redbook.com.au/. I added more information into the answer. If you have questions then let me know, would happily answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used https://www.redbook.com.au/ for MRSP.

There you have to take count that it is Australian site and therefore you need to do your own currency transformation.

You need to determine the need of the inclusion of VAT and sometimes you need to adjust the price with the inflation.